# Inheritance for File Associations under Windows XP?

Tags: windows, file-association

Is there something like "inheritance" for Windows file associations? I have a file type called rrx that is just a XML file. Now if I open explorer's context menu for a rrx file, I would like it to show all actions registered for XML files (Open in IE, XML Notepad etc.) as well as **my** actions written especially for rrx files. Is there a way to tell Windows: Handle files with extension rrx as XML files plus this additional stuff?

Comment: Apparently somebody downvoted me. Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in Windows help:

> To associate a file name extension with a file type:
>
> 1. Open Folder Options in Control Panel.
> 2. Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
> 3. Double-click Folder Options.
> 4. On the File Types tab, click New.
> 5. Type a new or existing file name extension, and then click Advanced.
> 6. In Associated File Type, select a different file type to associate with the extension.

If you click New and type in rrx, you can associate that with XML document, so you can then use the XML document default programs.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Maybe I don't see the obvious, but doesn't this miss the "plus my actions" part?

Comment: You can add your own actions there for the rrx files. I think that your custom actions for .XML Documents should be carried over too, but I'm not sure.

Comment: AFAICT I can associate .rrx with "XML Document" and then edit the actions for "XML Document" which changes the context menu for .xml files, too, OR detach .rrx from "XML Document" again. I wasn't able to say "all from 'XML Document', plus this one".

Answer (score 0):

I think you will like [Nirsoft FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html).

Create a new entry for your .rrx file and do not fill out any of the entries, then right click and choose `Replace File Type For Selected Extension` and choose `XML File`, you should not have every option for your `.RRX` file as you would have on any `.XML` file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of advanced file association editors available. They might do the job.

http://www.angelfire.com/biz/rhaminisys/fileasoc.html

http://www.xs4all.nl/~wstudios/Associate/index.html